# jQuery validate plugin - how to prevent submit if invalide

Tags: jquery, forms, validation, submit

I'm  using the jQuery validation plugin and it works to show the error messages.
However, if someone submits the form without fixing the required fields, the form still submits.

How to do I tell jQuery that if the form is invalid, it should NOT submit the form or do anything else (like fade out etc.)?

Here is my code:

```
$(function(){
$("#my-form").validate();
});

$(function(){
$('form[name="required-form"]').submit(function(event){
    $('#required-form').fadeOut("slow", function () {
    $('#optional-form').fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Instead, I want to say something like this:

```
$(function(){
$("#my-form").validate();
});

$(function(){
$('form[name="required-form"]').submit(function(event){
    // ONLY IF THE FORM IS VALID, ALLOW THE FORM TO SUBMIT, AND THEN CONTINUE BELOW
    $('#required-form').fadeOut("slow", function () {
    $('#optional-form').fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: There are many plugins to validate. What of them are you using?

Comment: jquery-validation-1.11.1

I don't mind switching to another plugin though. I just need something simple that will display text like "Please enter a valid email address" if the email address is invalid or if the name is not filled out. and then it should prevent form submission (and prevent the form from fading out) until the errors are fixed.

(Thanks for the quick reply!)

Comment: I would ideally like to just write my own validation code that says: if the name input field is empty, show the div that says 'Error'. and if the email input field does not contain an "@" symbol, then show a div that says 'Error'. otherwise, allow the form to submit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While submitting form using javascript or jquery the form gets submitted even if the fields marked as required have been left empty.

You can set the id of the textbox that is required to `txtBox` and use the following code-

```
$(function(){
$("#my-form").validate();
});

$(function(){
if($("#txtBox").val() != ""){
$('form[name="required-form"]').submit(function(event){
    $('#required-form').fadeOut("slow", function () {
    $('#optional-form').fadeIn("slow");
}
else{alert('Please fill in the required fields');}
});
```

You can also make use of the onsubmit event of the form ie. `<form onsubmit="return validate()">` to do so. That can be done as follows-

```
$(function(){
$("#my-form").validate();
});

$(function(){
if($("#txtBox").val() == ""){return false;}
else{ 
return true;
//fade in and fade out here 
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks! That does seem to prevent the form from being submitted when the required fields are not filled... however, my fade in, fade out does not work. This what my code looks like now:
    $(function(){
    $("#ss-form").validate();
     });
    
    $(function(){
    if($(".required").val() == ""){return false;}
    else{ 
    return true;
    $('#required-form').fadeOut("slow");
    }
    });

Comment: Try the first option that I have given in my answer, your fade in fade out will work for that

Answer (score -2):

The problem will become more clear if you post your html code.

The code that you have posted have missing brackets, that may have created the problem. Normally, jQuery validation plugin does not submit the invalid form.

To display custom validation messages refer:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/

Comment: This should have been a comment and not an answer.